# Display images in linux terminal using C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to display images in a linux kitty terminal with C++. I already have a script for bash that uses kitty's icat to display images. Is it possible to use icat within C++ in order to display images or are there other similar solutions?

Comment: If the question is whether you can run another program from C++ on linux, the answer is yes through `fork` and `exec` - that is what bash does under the hood. But it is not C++ specific...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding fork, exec, and wait in C++ (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754510/understanding-fork-exec-and-wait-in-c-linux)